# Replit Discord bot doesn't even log in

Tags: discord.js, replit

I have a problem with this bot, it's my first bot and I seem to have done everything right but is offline and nothing gets logged.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [8] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Logged in as bot!");
  client.user.setActivity(`Locating new targets for synthesis.`, { type: "WATCHING" });
});

client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong')
  }
});

client.login("BOT_TOKEN");
```

I have no idea what is wrong, I readded the bot, reset the token, and tried different code arrangements from different people. This is a dead end.

Comment: Chances are that its due to discord rate limiting Replit with the amount of bots being hosted there. See this [Replit Ask topic](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522?u=not-ethan) for more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replit is not a good idea for host your discord bot but if you want it work, go to the `shell` part and write `kill 1` and then restart the bot

Comment: The bot is on an empty server I know about the token thanks. What does kill 1 do in detail?

Comment: Discord's API tends to rate-limit Replit IPs. The `kill 1` command resets your server and your IP meaning the bot will be able to connect to the Discord API again.